# GTKADA GUI library : Drawing line and boxes

Tags: user-interface, line, draw, gtkada, ada95

I am trying to create a GUI as attached image using GTKADA Library, using gtkada.style package by calling below mentioned procedure,

Draw_Line(Cr:Cairo.Cairo_Context;Color:Gdk.Color.Gdk_Color;X1,Y1,X2,Y2:Glib.Gint)

How to define the value for **Cr : Cairo.Cairo_Context**,what are the packages needs to be included, Can someone let me know how to achieve a GUI as mentioned in the Image by using GTKADA library.Expecting to have a GUI which contains lines, boxes and text using GTKada library as mentioned in attached image.
[CONTAINER GUI Using GTKada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH1xG.png)